# Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, routes, kohana

standart `Hello World` is working good:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

if I change to other Controller, for example Controller/Site/Test.php then I have an error message:

> Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL / was not found on
>   this server.

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'site'
        'controller' => 'test',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Controllers are okey **Test.php**:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Test extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->response->body('hello, t world!');
    }

} // End Test
```

**Bootstrap.php**

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/',
    'index_file' => FALSE,
));
```

**.htaccess**

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

structure domen `http://kohanafr` in `/var/www/html/kohanafr`

tunes `virtualhost`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName kohanafr
    ServerAlias www.kohanafr
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/kohanafr
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

apache `config`:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

add. to this error code:

`SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Request/Client/Internal.php [ 80 ]`

```
75          if ( ! class_exists($prefix.$controller))
76          {
77              throw HTTP_Exception::factory(404,
78                  'The requested URL :uri was not found on this server.',
79                  array(':uri' => $request->uri())
80              )->request($request);
81          }
82 
83          // Load the controller using reflection
84          $class = new ReflectionClass($prefix.$controller);
85
```

**`1. SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Request/Client.php [ 114 ] » Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute_request(arguments)`**

0

```
object Request(19) {
    protected _requested_with => NULL
    protected _method => string(3) "GET"
    protected _protocol => string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
    protected _secure => bool FALSE
    protected _referrer => NULL
    protected _route => object Route(5) {
        protected _filters => array(0) 
        protected _uri => string(32) "(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))"
        protected _regex => array(0) 
        protected _defaults => array(3) (
            "directory" => string(4) "site"
            "controller" => string(4) "test"
            "action" => string(5) "index"
        )
        protected _route_regex => string(95) "#^(?:(?P<controller>[^/.,;?\n]++)(?:/(?P<action>[^/.,;?\n]++)(?:/(?P<id>[^/.,;?\n]++))?)?)?$#uD"
    }
    protected _routes => array(0) 
    protected _header => object HTTP_Header(0) {
    }
    protected _body => NULL
    protected _directory => string(4) "Site"
    protected _controller => string(4) "Test"
    protected _action => string(5) "index"
    protected _uri => string(0) ""
    protected _external => bool FALSE
    protected _params => array(0) 
    protected _get => array(0) 
    protected _post => array(0) 
    protected _cookies => array(0) 
    protected _client => object Request_Client_Internal(9) {
        protected _previous_environment => NULL
        protected _cache => NULL
        protected _follow => bool FALSE
        protected _follow_headers => array(1) (
            0 => string(13) "authorization"
        )
        protected _strict_redirect => bool TRUE
        protected _header_callbacks => array(1) (
            "Location" => string(34) "Request_Client::on_header_location"
        )
        protected _max_callback_depth => integer 5
        protected _callback_depth => integer 1
        protected _callback_params => array(0) 
    }
}
```

1

```
object Response(5) {
    protected _status => integer 200
    protected _header => object HTTP_Header(0) {
    }
    protected _body => string(0) ""
    protected _cookies => array(0) 
    protected _protocol => string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
}
```

**2.  SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Request.php [ 993 ] » Kohana_Request_Client->execute(arguments)**

0

```
object Request(19) {
    protected _requested_with => NULL
    protected _method => string(3) "GET"
    protected _protocol => string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
    protected _secure => bool FALSE
    protected _referrer => NULL
    protected _route => object Route(5) {
        protected _filters => array(0) 
        protected _uri => string(32) "(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))"
        protected _regex => array(0) 
        protected _defaults => array(3) (
            "directory" => string(4) "site"
            "controller" => string(4) "test"
            "action" => string(5) "index"
        )
        protected _route_regex => string(95) "#^(?:(?P<controller>[^/.,;?\n]++)(?:/(?P<action>[^/.,;?\n]++)(?:/(?P<id>[^/.,;?\n]++))?)?)?$#uD"
    }
    protected _routes => array(0) 
    protected _header => object HTTP_Header(0) {
    }
    protected _body => NULL
    protected _directory => string(4) "Site"
    protected _controller => string(4) "Test"
    protected _action => string(5) "index"
    protected _uri => string(0) ""
    protected _external => bool FALSE
    protected _params => array(0) 
    protected _get => array(0) 
    protected _post => array(0) 
    protected _cookies => array(0) 
    protected _client => object Request_Client_Internal(9) {
        protected _previous_environment => NULL
        protected _cache => NULL
        protected _follow => bool FALSE
        protected _follow_headers => array(1) (
            0 => string(13) "authorization"
        )
        protected _strict_redirect => bool TRUE
        protected _header_callbacks => array(1) (
            "Location" => string(34) "Request_Client::on_header_location"
        )
        protected _max_callback_depth => integer 5
        protected _callback_depth => integer 1
        protected _callback_params => array(0) 
    }
}
```

**3.  DOCROOT/index.php [ 118 ] » Kohana_Request->execute()**

```
113     /**
114      * Execute the main request. A source of the URI can be passed, eg: $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'].
115      * If no source is specified, the URI will be automatically detected.
116      */
117     echo Request::factory(TRUE, array(), FALSE)
118         ->execute()
119         ->send_headers(TRUE)
120         ->body();
121 }
```

**Internal.php** `echo Debug::vars($_SERVER,$request,$request->uri())`

```
echo Debug::vars($_SERVER,$request,$request->uri());            


            if ( ! class_exists($prefix.$controller))
            {
                throw HTTP_Exception::factory(404,
                    'The requested URL :uri was not found on this server.',
                    array(':uri' => $request->uri())
                )->request($request);
            }
```

dump:

```
array(29) (
    "HTTP_HOST" => string(8) "kohanafr"
    "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => string(74) "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0"
    "HTTP_ACCEPT" => string(63) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
    "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => string(13) "gzip, deflate"
    "HTTP_CONNECTION" => string(10) "keep-alive"
    "PATH" => string(60) "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    "SERVER_SIGNATURE" => string(69) "<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at kohanafr Port 80</address>
"
    "SERVER_SOFTWARE" => string(22) "Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)"
    "SERVER_NAME" => string(8) "kohanafr"
    "SERVER_ADDR" => string(9) "127.0.0.1"
    "SERVER_PORT" => string(2) "80"
    "REMOTE_ADDR" => string(9) "127.0.0.1"
    "DOCUMENT_ROOT" => string(22) "/var/www/html/kohanafr"
    "REQUEST_SCHEME" => string(4) "http"
    "CONTEXT_PREFIX" => string(0) ""
    "CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT" => string(22) "/var/www/html/kohanafr"
    "SERVER_ADMIN" => string(19) "webmaster@localhost"
    "SCRIPT_FILENAME" => string(32) "/var/www/html/kohanafr/index.php"
    "REMOTE_PORT" => string(5) "43568"
    "GATEWAY_INTERFACE" => string(7) "CGI/1.1"
    "SERVER_PROTOCOL" => string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
    "REQUEST_METHOD" => string(3) "GET"
    "QUERY_STRING" => string(0) ""
    "REQUEST_URI" => string(1) "/"
    "SCRIPT_NAME" => string(10) "/index.php"
    "PHP_SELF" => string(10) "/index.php"
    "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => float 1474108538.614
    "REQUEST_TIME" => integer 1474108538
)
object Request(19) {
    protected _requested_with => NULL
    protected _method => string(3) "GET"
    protected _protocol => string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
    protected _secure => bool FALSE
    protected _referrer => NULL
    protected _route => object Route(5) {
        protected _filters => array(0) 
        protected _uri => string(32) "(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))"
        protected _regex => array(0) 
        protected _defaults => array(3) (
            "directory" => string(4) "site"
            "controller" => string(4) "test"
            "action" => string(5) "index"
        )
        protected _route_regex => string(95) "#^(?:(?P<controller>[^/.,;?\n]++)(?:/(?P<action>[^/.,;?\n]++)(?:/(?P<id>[^/.,;?\n]++))?)?)?$#uD"
    }
    protected _routes => array(0) 
    protected _header => object HTTP_Header(0) {
    }
    protected _body => NULL
    protected _directory => string(4) "Site"
    protected _controller => string(4) "Test"
    protected _action => string(5) "index"
    protected _uri => string(0) ""
    protected _external => bool FALSE
    protected _params => array(0) 
    protected _get => array(0) 
    protected _post => array(0) 
    protected _cookies => array(0) 
    protected _client => object Request_Client_Internal(9) {
        protected _previous_environment => NULL
        protected _cache => NULL
        protected _follow => bool FALSE
        protected _follow_headers => array(1) (
            0 => string(13) "authorization"
        )
        protected _strict_redirect => bool TRUE
        protected _header_callbacks => array(1) (
            "Location" => string(34) "Request_Client::on_header_location"
        )
        protected _max_callback_depth => integer 5
        protected _callback_depth => integer 1
        protected _callback_params => array(0) 
    }
}
string(1) "/"
```

Answer (score 0):

The value for `directory` in `defaults()` needs to match the directory's name in case, so you need:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'Site'  /* Note capital 'S' */
        'controller' => 'test',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'site'
        'controller' => 'test',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

There is no «directory» part in your route. So when you open Controller/Site/Test it'll be parsed that way:

```
controller => Controller
action => Site
id => Test
```

Fix your routes